# class declaration with generics java

Tags: java, generics, scjp

```
class a{}
class b extends a{}
class c <? extends b> extends b{}
public class d {
      public static void main(String[] args) {  
        c<c> n = new c<c>(); 
      }
}
```

I am reading SCJP. I didn't get the concept of generic class with `class<?>` and `class<? extends anything>`.....if it means we can pass any class which extends "anything" then why above code is not working?

Please explain this , its very confusing

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to declare a class with a type parameter without ever referring to that parameter. Therefore it is not foreseen to declare such a class. You have to give the type parameter a name.

Change

```
class c <? extends b> extends b{}
```

to

```
class c <T extends b> extends b{}
```

Within the class `c` you can now refer to the type parameter `T`, e.g. to declare methods and variables.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the exact error message, but I guess it's about that you can't use wild cards when you define the type parameters.

Try:

```
class c <T extends b> extends b{}
```

Note: It's a convention to start class names with a capital letter, so use:

```
class C <T extends B> extends B{}
```